# Set dynamic value for property of ASP.Net Control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, controls, ascx

I'm trying to pass a dynamic variable into a control:

```
<% foreach(var product in CartModel.Products) { %>
    <kc:Warning runat="server" id="Warning" ProductId="<%= product.ProductId %>" />
%>
```

but when I access ProductId in the control (in /ProductAvailabilityWarning.ascx.cs), it's being passed as literally `"<%= product.ProductId %>"`, not as the value of `product.ProductId`.

I'd rather not rewrite all of my code as a Repeater, since there's a ton of dynamic code inside the foreach block that I'd have to modify.

EDIT: Since this code appears to be confusing, due to being a Frankenstein monstrosity of legacy code, here's a more complete snippet of the code, and why I'm trying to avoid rewriting the whole thing as a Repeater

```
<% foreach(var product in CartModel.Products) { %>
<kc:Warning runat="server" id="Warning" ProductId="<%= product.ProductId %>" />

<div class="cart-product js-cart-product">
    <div class="cart-product__product-details">
        <div class="cart-product__name"><%= product.ProductName %></div>
        <div class="cart-product__details">
            <div class="cart-product__detail-label"><%= product.MaturityLabel %></div>
            <div class="cart-product__detail-description"><%= product.RelativeMaturity %> <%= Dictionary.GetValue("eBusiness", "days" ) %></div>
            <ul class="cart-product__detail-icons">
                <% foreach(var maturityIcon in product.MaturityIcons) { %>
                <li>
                    <img
                        src="<%= maturityIcon.Src %>"
                        alt="" />
                    <span class="badge-label"><%= maturityIcon.Alt %></span>
                </li>
                <% } %>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-product__treatments-label">
            <%= Dictionary.GetValue("eBusiness", "seed treatments selected" ) %>
        </div>
        <ul class="cart-product__treament-grid">
                <% foreach(var seedTreatmentImage in product.SeedTreatmentImages) { %>
                <li class="cart-product__selected-treatment"> 
                    <img
                    src="<%= seedTreatmentImage.Src %>"
                    alt="<%= seedTreatmentImage.Alt %>" />
                </li>
                <% } %>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-product__order-totals">
        <% if (product != null && product.ProductBagImage != null) { %>
        <div class="cart-product__logo">
            <img width="325" height="500"
                src="<%= product.ProductBagImage.Src %>"
                alt="<%= product.ProductBagImage.Alt %>" />
        </div>
        <% } %>
        <div class="cart-product__quantity">
            <span class="cart-product__value"><%= product.Quantity %></span>
            <% if (product.Size == eBusiness.Sizes.Bag) { %>
            <span class="cart-product__label"><%= Dictionary.GetValue("eBusiness", "size_bags" ) %></span>
            <% } else if (product.Size == eBusiness.Sizes.Tote) { %>
            <span class="cart-product__label"><%= Dictionary.GetValue("eBusiness", "size_totes" ) %></span>
            <% } else if (product.Size == eBusiness.Sizes.SeedPak) { %>
            <span class="cart-product__label"><%= Dictionary.GetValue("eBusiness", "size_seedpaks" ) %></span>
            <% } %>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-product__acres">
            <span class="cart-product__value"><%= product.Acres %></span>
            <span class="cart-product__label"><%= Dictionary.GetValue("eBusiness", "acres") %></span>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-product__divider"></div>
        <div class="cart-product__total">
            <sup class="cart-product__currency">$</sup>
            <span class="cart-product__value"><%= product.Msrp.ToString("0,0.00") %></span>
            <span class="cart-product__label"><%= Dictionary.GetValue("eBusiness", "MSRP") %></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% if(ShowRemoveButton){ %>
    <div class="cart-product__remove">
        <button
            class="cart-product__cta-button js-cart-product__remove"
            type="button"
            data-bundle-id="<%= product.BundleId %>">
            <img src="/build/img/svg-sprite/icon-garbage.svg" alt="" />
            <span><%= Dictionary.GetValue("eBusiness", "remove") %></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <% } %>
    <% if(ShowEditButton){ %>
    <div class="cart-product__edit">
        <a href='<%= ProductCustomizationBaseUrl + product.ProductId + "&c=" + product.BundleId %>' class="cart-product__cta-button">
            <img src="/build/img/icon-edit.svg" alt="" />
            <span><%= Dictionary.GetValue("eBusiness", "edit") %></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with ASP.NET MVC? ASP.NET MVC does not use controls (i.e. `System.Web.UI.Control` ) excepting for UserControls, but only when rendered as a `Partial`, _not_ using `runat="server"`).

Comment: It looks like you're confusing the (ancient and horrible) WebForms data-binding syntax (`<%#`, which was used to populate properties of `WebControl` instances in a page) with ASP.NET MVC's support for using ASPX/ASCX files as control-less views and partial-views. Please clarify by telling us the project's history and _exactly what_ is going on... (you _can_ use .ascx as partial-views in ASP.NET MVC, and you can instantiate them in a page, just not with `runat="server", you need to use a different technique). But ideally you should be using Razor `.cshtml` instead...

Comment: This is a very old legacy project with a horrible mishmash of code. Just switching to .cshtml is not an option. Within the foreach, other properties are set with <%= product.XXX %>

Comment: So this is a legacy WebForms project, that isn't using any `Controller` classes at all? (so where is `CartModel` coming from?) Is there any similar logic in any other pages in the project that already-works that you can base your changes off?

Comment: No. There are other Controls that have properties set on them, but the properties are hardcoded in the code. This is the only place where I need to pass in a dynamic property

Answer (score 2):

- Remove the `<kc:Warning/>` control syntax, controls *don't work like that*.

  - Under WebForms, controls are instantiated in `Init` (IIRC), then have their properties set during `__VIEWDATA`'s deserialization events and again in the data-binding events (but only for `<%# %>`-style syntax).
  - The `<%= %>` syntax denotes a call to `HtmlTextWriter.Write()` which simply writes the inner string value to the output stream, and it's only invoked during the page's render-function: so the `<%= %>` syntax cannot be used to set properties of controls (only `<%# %>` can be used for that, but only if you're using WebForms' (horribly complicated) data-binding system.
- If you want to load a `UserControl` (aka `.ascx`) and just use it render HTML without faffing around with WebForm's control lifecycle and
  old-and-horrible data-binding system the good news is: **you can!**

  - There is a tiny bit of legwork involved, but it's straightforward to understand, and that's is what this answer is all about.

Like so:

1. Use `Page.LoadControl(String virtualPath)` to get a `Control` object instance representing your user-control.

   - The `virtualPath` argument will be a `const String` like `~/MyControls/Warning.ascx` or similar.
2. Cast the result to your specific `UserControl` subclass (the type defined in your `.ascx`'s code-behind file.
3. Then inside the loop body set the properties then call `RenderControl`, passing the (hidden) `__w` object from your `.aspx`'s render function.

Like so:

**MyPage.aspx**:

```
<%
    MyWarningControl warningCtrl = (MyWarningControl)this.LoadControl("~/MyControls/Warning.ascx");
%>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

<%    foreach(var product in CartModel.Products) { %>
<%
    warningCtrl.ProductId = product.ProductId;
    warningCtrl.AnythingElse = product;

    warningCtrl.RenderControl( __w );
%>

<div class="cart-product js-cart-product">

<!-- etc --> 
</div>

<% } /*foreach product*/ %>
```

---

You can simplify things somewhat if you add a custom `Render` function to your `UserControl`'s code-behind class, like so:

Also, [you can also use ASP.NET Core-style constructor-dependency injection](https://github.com/Jehoel/AspNetDependencyInjection) into your `UserControl`'s if you're feeling adventurous (and are running on .NET Framework 4.7.2 or later).

```
public static class LoadingExtensions
{
    public static MyWarningControl LoadMyWarningControl( this Page p )
    {
        MyWarningControl warningCtrl = (MyWarningControl)p.LoadControl( "~/MyControls/Warning.ascx" );
        return warningCtrl;
    }
}

public partial class MyWarningControl : UserControl
{
    public void RenderProduct( HtmlTextWriter w, Product p )
    {
        if( w is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(w) );

        try
        {
            this.Product = p ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(p) );

            this.RenderControl( w );
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Product = null;
        }
    }

    public Product Product { get; private set; }

    public Int32 ProductId => this.Product.ProductId;
}
```

Then your `.aspx` logic simplifies down to just this:

```
<%
    MyWarningControl warningCtrl = this.LoadMyWarningControl();
%>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

<%    foreach(var product in CartModel.Products) { %>
<%
   warningCtrl.RenderProduct( __w, product );
%>

<div class="cart-product js-cart-product">

<!-- etc --> 
</div>

<% } /*foreach product*/ %>
```

Much simpler!

---

If you're wondering where `__w` comes from: it's the `HtmlTextWriter` where your HTML is being written to. It's passed as a parameter into the *render function* generated from your `.aspx` file.

You can see it yourself by loading the `.dll` file generated by `aspnet_compiler.exe` into ILSpy and locating the generated `__Render_controlN` method in your `Page` subclass, for example:

[image]

So every occurrence of `<%= x %>` and `<%: y %>` is converted to `__w.Write(x);` and `__w.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(y));` respectively.

...which also explains why `<asp:SomeControl runat="server" PropertyName="<%= x %>" />` isn't allowed: because `<asp:SomeControl` is an object with its own logic and render function, and not just plaintext that's passed through `HtmlTextWriter`.